# Logging format for Flask on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, logging, flask, wsgi, pythonanywhere

I'm running a Flask web app on PythonAnywhere. The access logs `xyz.pythonanywhere.com.access.log` have the format:

```
12.34.167.189 - - [07/Aug/2018:04:33:46 +0000] "GET /foo/bar?id=abc HTTP/1.1" 200 117942 "-" "-" "12.34.167.189" response-time=0.041
```

I'm trying to get rid of the IPs.

All approaches modifying or overriding the logger didn't work. The following lines successfully effect the logging on my local machine:

```
import logging
from werkzeug.serving import WSGIRequestHandler
logger = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
WSGIRequestHandler.log = lambda self, type, msg, *args: getattr(logger, type)(msg % args)
```

On PythonAnywhere, however, Flask is started differently from `/var/www/xyz_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py`. The logging format didn't change.

So, how can I configure the WSGI logging?

Comment: Have you tried putting your logger overriding code at the end of the `/var/www/xyz_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The access log is not run through Python. That's directly from nginx. There is no way to change it.

Comment: Thanks, Glenn! Does that mean there is no chance to avoid saving IPs to the log files? That would be bad considering the new GDPR (General Data Protection Regulation) in Europe. :(

Comment: You can have a daily script that wipes your access logs (or backs it up after stripping the IP and then wipes it). Unfortunately you definitely need that IP. (eg: that's how you send the http response back to the client side!) I believe you can just state/let your users know that you temporarily have their IP addresses?

Comment: It's worth noting that log files are rotated -- that is, after some time they will be deleted.   So all you really need is a note in your privacy policy saying "we collect normal web logs" (exact terminology would probably depend on your jurisdiction) and you'll be fine.   The PythonAnywhere privacy policy has wording to that effect.